# How to fix Mac o Linker (id Error)

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, unity-game-engine

Here is the console error

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_UnityAdsUnityWrapperDelegate in:
/Users/user128663/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-chmuwvieslknrzcedvfymumvcref/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityAdsUnityWrapper-6D362980BD529555.o
/Users/user128663/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-chmuwvieslknrzcedvfymumvcref/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityAdsUnityWrapper-C0876E5C44C1B258.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_UnityAdsUnityWrapperDelegate in:
/Users/user128663/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-chmuwvieslknrzcedvfymumvcref/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityAdsUnityWrapper-6D362980BD529555.o
/Users/user128663/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-chmuwvieslknrzcedvfymumvcref/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityAdsUnityWrapper-C0876E5C44C1B258.o
ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
```

I cant figure out what is going on, I've tried deleting those specific files.

Comment: Could you provide more context?

Comment: it's a unity game, im new to devlopment and I have no idea what to do, litterally no idea. I got the license, codesigning, etc

Comment: Briefly the Linker is the program that takes the output of the compiler and try to links them to create the 'final' executable. In your case, the linker is telling you that there are some elements that are duplicated. And seems like is related with Unity Ads (UnityAdsUnityWrapperDelegate). So, maybe trying to check the steps that you did when you included Unity Ads can give you a clue !

Answer (score 0):

It means you have included duplicate files or frameworks in the project. Do the following to solve the issue

Go to Xcode Build Settings -> set `GCC_NO_COMMON_BLOCKS` to `YES`

Also set `enable testability` to `NO` in build settings

Comment: that didnt work, I still get the same error, what else should i do?